# Concept of negative mass; gravitational field problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, mass, density

Almost all of us are acquainted with the problem of calculating the gravitational field inside a bore which is in a solid. Many of the solution manuals I have seen, like to follow the negative mass density method.

I am not convinced why this method works. All solution manual seem to follow it blindly. So, why does it work?

Comment: A link to the definition of the method?

Deeper inside a solid sphere the force of gravity is reduced until in the center it is zero. Is that what you want to know about?

Comment: It works because newtonian gravity is additive. If $F=F_1+F_2$, then $F_1=F-F_2$, so you can imagine $F_1$ as the force $F$ plus the force $f= -F_1$, identical to an "antiforce"

Comment: @HughMungus Your comment is almost the correct answer. Why not write a neat answer to this question?

Comment: @Mockingbird please add a description of the negative mass concept so that someone who hasn't heard of it can understand

Comment: @YashasSamaga the reason is laziness (well, no, I am actually busy), but if the OP find it unclear I will expand it into an answer

Comment: @Hugh Mungus I think I get your comment. +1